# Post not redirecting to the show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a simple ruby on rails blog. When a user submits a post, i want them to be redirected to the posts show page. Instead of being redirected I'm getting a `NoMethodError in PostsController#create` - `undefined method 'post_path' for #<PostsController:0x007ff379d72110> Did you mean? posts_path post_params root_path` error.

post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController 
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    def new 
        @post = Post.new 
    end 

    def create 
        @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
        if @post.save 
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else 
            render :new 
        end
    end 

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end


    private 
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :all_tags)
    end 
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1 class="show_title">
<%=@post.title%>
</h1>
<p class="show_date">submiited <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) ago%></p>
<p class="show_body"><%=@post.body%></p>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'homes#show'
  resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  resources :posts, only: [:new, :create]
  resource :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Comment: you would need to show what you have in your routes.rb file

Comment: @fanta added routes.

Comment: I see, you're trying to redirect to the `show` action, but you only defined your routes for `new` and `create`, add `show` there as well: `resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :show]`

Comment: thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

remove `resources :posts, only: [:new, :create]` and just put
`resources :posts`. That way you'll have the `post_path(@post)` you are trying to redirect to

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add show action in your allowed routes

```
resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :show]
```

and then you can simply do this in your create action

```
def create 
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  if @post.save 
    redirect_to @post
  else 
    render :new 
  end 
end
```

It should work fine.